# LINQ Query to determine whether or not a relationship exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In this program, I have 3 models: `Client`, `Brokerage` and `Subscription`. A `Subscription` connects Clients to Brokerages. A Client has a subscription to one or many brokerages.

```
public class Client
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required, StringLength(50), DisplayName("Last Name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [Required, StringLength(50), DisplayName("First Name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [DataType(DataType.Date),DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true),Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

  [DisplayName("Full Name")] 
  public string FullName
  {
    get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
  }

  public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Brokerage
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), DisplayName("Registration Number"), Required]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [DataType(DataType.Currency), Column(TypeName="money")]
  public decimal Fee { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Subscription
{
  public int ClientId { get; set; }
  public string BrokerageId { get; set; }
  public Client Client { get; set; }
  public Brokerage Brokerage { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, I am trying to write a LINQ query so that a user gets a list of existing brokerages, and the option to either subscribe or unsubscribe from that brokerage depending on whether or not the user is subscribed to the brokerage.

To do this, I have a ViewModel that contains the BrokerageId, the Title of the brokerage, and a boolean to represent if the client is a member or not. This ViewModel gets created in the Controller with this LINQ query:

```
var subscriptions = (
  from b in _context.Brokerages
  join s in _context.Subscriptions on b.Id equals s.BrokerageId
  select new BrokerageSubscriptionsViewModel
  {
    BrokerageId = b.Id,
    Title = b.Title,
    IsMember = s.ClientId == id
  }).ToList();
```

This is *almost* working.

The expected result should be as follows for a user that is subscribed to all brokerages:

```
A1 : {Unsubscribe}
A2 : {Unsubscribe}
A3 : {Unsubscribe}
```

But what I'm getting is the results from the entire Subscription table,

```
A1 : {Unsubscribe}
A1 : {Subscribe}
A1 : {Subscribe}
A2 : {Unsubscribe}
A2 : {Subscribe}
A2 : {Subscribe}
```

This is because it is pulling all the rows from the Subscription table, and if the client ID doesn't match, it displays "duplicates". I have tried adding a `where s.ClientId == id` clause, but this makes it so that users who have no active subscriptions see nothing, when they should see the option to subscribe to any existing brokerages.

I've been struggling with this for a long time and would appreciate any help avaialable.

Comment: First, show the relationships between the models. Don't describe - show in code. Second, if the relationships are defined correctly - you won't need `join` in your LINQ statements. LINQ is *not* rewriting SQL and join in LINQ is code smell. You are describing your solution in terms of relational tables (duplicates, rows). You shouldn't! ;)

Comment: Hi Felix, I've updated the question with the code for the 3 models in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of `EXISTS` in Linq is `.Any()`.

If you have your relationships correctly defined then you can use navigation properties.

```cs
var subscriptions = (
  from b in _context.Brokerages
  select new BrokerageSubscriptionsViewModel
  {
    BrokerageId = b.Id,
    Title = b.Title,
    IsMember = b.Subscriptions.Any(),
  }).ToList();
```

Otherwise, use a "subquery"

```cs
var subscriptions = (
  from b in _context.Brokerages
  select new BrokerageSubscriptionsViewModel
  {
    BrokerageId = b.Id,
    Title = b.Title,
    IsMember = _context.Subscriptions.Any(s => b.Id == s.BrokerageId),
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: This was the answer! I just had to do a subquery on whether the subscription ClientID matched the parameter ID. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TysonMoyes - note, no `join`s. Also, looks like you have amany-to-many relationship between Clients and Brokerages. if it is that simple, you don't even need a subscription class; you can implement many-to-many directly. And read up on `SelectMany()` - it allows you to get many-to-many in an efficient way. The biggest thing - don't think of LINQ as "SQL in C#". It implements relationships between object, not tables